# How can I make the repository take more than one column?

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-database

The below code is from an APP I am making based on another simple APP where the Entity had only one column.
Now I have added another column (materialBrand) and I am having difficulties in implementing the same on the repository class in the AsynkTask.
Please Help.

This is the class Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "material_table")
public class MaterialEntity {

    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "material_name")
    private String mMaterialName;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "material_brand")
    private String mMaterialBrand;

    public MaterialEntity(@NonNull String materialName, String materialBrand) {
        this.mMaterialName = materialName;
        this.mMaterialBrand = materialBrand;
    }

    public String getMaterialName(){
        return this.mMaterialName;
    }

    public String getMaterialBrand(){
        return this.mMaterialBrand;
    }
}
```

This is the Dao:

```
@Dao
public interface MaterialDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(MaterialEntity materialName, MaterialEntity materialBrand);

    @Query("DELETE FROM material_table")
    void deleteAll();

    @Query("SELECT * from material_table ORDER BY material_name ASC")
    LiveData<List<MaterialEntity>> getAllMaterials();
}
```

This is the Repository Class:

```
public class MaterialRepository {

    private MaterialDao mMaterialDao;
    private LiveData<List<MaterialEntity>> mAllMaterial;

    public MaterialRepository(Application application) {
        MaterialRoomDatabase db = MaterialRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mMaterialDao = db.materialDao();
        mAllMaterial = mMaterialDao.getAllMaterials();
    }

    public LiveData<List<MaterialEntity>> getAllMaterials() {
        return mAllMaterial;
    }

    public void insert (MaterialEntity materialName, MaterialEntity materialBrand) {
        new insertAsyncTask(mMaterialDao).execute(materialName, materialBrand);
    }

    private static class insertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<MaterialEntity, Void, Void> {

        private MaterialDao mAsyncTaskDao;

        insertAsyncTask(MaterialDao dao) {
            mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final MaterialEntity... params) {
            mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: normally when you make changes to database columns you need to uninstall and install your app again. Have you done that ?

Comment: actually am getting an error in  mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]); which says  "insert (MaterialEntity, MaterialEntity) in MaterialDao cannot be applied to (MaterialEntity)

Comment: post error as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below insert method has two params as args

@Dao
public interface MaterialDao {

```
@Insert
void insert(MaterialEntity materialName, MaterialEntity materialBrand);

@Query("DELETE FROM material_table")
void deleteAll();

@Query("SELECT * from material_table ORDER BY material_name ASC")
LiveData<List<MaterialEntity>> getAllMaterials();

}
```

You cannot send only one param.

```
  mAsyncTaskDao.insert(params[0]);
```